# Error in `label=` argument input. conflicts with add_overal() in tbl_summary

Tags: label, summary, tbl

I am using tbl_summary function to develope a table for my analysi and it keeps on throwing  Error in `label=` argument input. Select from ‘age’, ‘age_cat’,  ‘respo_cat’ when I "add_overa()" function else it runs well. Here is my code.

`main %>% select(sex,age,age_cat,respo_cat)%>% tbl_summary( by = "sex", label = list(sex ~"Sex", age ~"Age", age_cat ~"Age Category", respo_cat ~ "Respondent"), type = all_continuous() ~ "continuous2", statistic = list(age~c("{mean}({sd})", "{median}")), sort = c(respo_cat)~"frequency" ) %>%  add_overall()`

I haven't found headways